# how to change test ads to live ads in admob for ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I am using Admob ads in my ios(swift) app. I have done showing ads in test mode, how to change it for live mode before I move it into app store. 
->Is there any change of adunit id for test mode and live mode?->what is the procedure for using live ads?->how to add custom ads to our own app?
please provide procedure or links